# Python HTTPConnectionPool error

Tags: python, http

I'm trying to run a python script (that is not mine) which is supposed to connect to an IP address (192.168.1.3) on the LAN.

```
  File "control/insert_to_container.py", line 36, in <module>
    res=read_info.open_file()
  File "/control/read_info.py", line 21, in open_file
    r = requests.get('http://'+line.rstrip('\t')+':491155')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 508, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.1.3', port=491155): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f8fd9e9b250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

I specified the IP address in a config file. Would anybody know what the `%09` is in the error `HTTPConnectionPool(host=192.168.1.3%09`. I wondering if this is the source of the error.

Comment: Please add your error message as code-formatted text instead of the image.

Comment: Somehow a tab got into the hostname.

Comment: @KlausD. ah ok thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable "line" contains a tab, which is then turned into "%09" by the Requests library.

To fix this, you must first ensure that your "line" variable contains no extraneous characters.  The most direct way to achieve this is to use `.rstrip()`

Example:

```
r = requests.get('http://'+line.rstrip('\t')+':49155')
```

Comment: thank you that removed the tab. However, it is still not connecting, should I removed the `' '` from the IP address?

Comment: "Connection refused" looks more like a networking error.  Are you sure the host you're connecting to has a service listening on that port?  Proper firewall configuration?